# What is a function $f : 2^n \rightarrow n$ such that for each $y \in n$ and $A \in 2^n$ there is $x \in n$ such that $f(\tau(x,A)) = y$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We first set up some notations and definitions:

- We view each positive integer $n$ as a (particular) set of $n$ elements. We also pick some bijection $\phi_n : 2^n \xrightarrow{\approx} \mathcal{P}(n)$, where the codomain denotes the power set of $n$.
- Define the function $\tau_n : n \times 2^n \rightarrow 2^n$ given by
  $$
  \tau(x,A) = 
  \left\{\begin{matrix}
  \phi^{-1}( \phi(A) \setminus\{x\} ) \,, & x \in \phi(A) \\ 
  \phi^{-1}( \phi(A) \cup\{x\} ) \,, & x \notin \phi(A) \\  
  \end{matrix}\right.
  $$
  where the implied subscript on each of the $\tau$'s,$\phi$'s in the above equation is $n$.

Then my question is:

> For which positive integers $n$ does there exist a function $f_n : 2^n \rightarrow n$ such that for each $A \in 2^n , y\in n$ there exists $x \in n$ such that $f_n(\tau_n(x,A)) = y$?

And for such $n$, how would we find such a function?

---

For background, the above question arises in considering the following puzzle:

> Alice and Bob are in prison, and the warden suggests a deal to them, where they will go free if they can win the following game: **0.** First Alice and Bob are allowed to devise a strategy on their own, after being told about this game. However, after they agree to start the game, Alice and Bob may have no further contact. **1.** The warden shows Alice an oriented $m\times m$ grid of coins, each of which will be randomly in either the heads or tails position. **2.** Next, the warden points to a (randomly chosen) particular coin position, say position $P$, which is seen by Alice. (He doesn't change the coins in any way.) **3.** Alice is then required to flip exactly one coin, of her choosing. (She may not avoid flipping any coins.) **4.** Alice leaves and Bob is shown the grid of coins. The two have had no contact since Alice saw the coins and Bob has not seen the coins before this. **5.** Bob must determine the position $P$, with no further input aside from looking at the coins. If this is accomplished, then Alice and Bob go free. The question is, for which $m$ is a winning strategy possible, and what would be such a strategy? Note: with the above notation, $n=m^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll denote $n$ as just cardinality of our set, and will assume that we work with set $\{0, 1, \ldots, n - 1\}$.

If $n$ is power of two, say that $f(B) = \bigoplus\limits_{t \in \phi(B)} t$. Then we have $f(\tau(x, A)) = \bigoplus\limits_{t \in \phi(A) \Delta \{x\}} t = \bigoplus\limits_{t \in \phi(A)} t \oplus x$. Taking $x = y \oplus \bigoplus\limits_{t \in \phi(A)} t$ we get $f(\tau(x, A)) = y$.

This approach doesn't work if $n$ is not power of $2$, because we can get $x \geq n$.

And indeed if $n$ isn't power of $2$, such $f$ doesn't exist.

Let $p(y) = |\{B | f(B) = y|$. Because $\sum\limits_{y = 0}^{n - 1} p(y) = 2^n$ and $n$ doesn't divide $2^n$, we have $p(y_0) < 2^n / n$ for some $y_0$.

For all $A$, let $B(A)$ be such that $f(B(A)) = y_0$ and, for some $x$, $B(A) = \tau(x, A)$. Because there total $2^n$ different values of $A$, and less than $2^n / n$ different values of $B(A)$, there are $n + 1$ different $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_{n + 1}$ such that $B(A_1) = B(A_2) = \ldots = B(A_{n + 1})$.

But that is impossible, because we have $|\phi(B(A)) \Delta \phi(A)| = 1$, and  $\phi(B(A_1)) \Delta \phi(A_i)$ should be different for different $i$, because we can recover $A_i$ from this value as $\phi^{-1}(\phi(B(A_1)) \Delta \phi(A_i) \Delta \phi(B(A_1)))$, but there are only $n$ different 1-element subsets.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask, what is the meaning of the $\bigoplus$ symbol in your answer?

Comment: Bitwise XOR. $a \oplus b$ is number that has $i$-th bit (digit when written in base 2) equal to $1$ iff exactly one of $a$ and $b$ has it equal to $1$.